# Rebuild angular-cli project whenever a file is added to assets

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm running an Angular project on `ng build --watch`, however everytime I add a new image to assets, I have to either manually rebuild the project or add the same image again in the `dist` folder. Is there a way to make it watch over the assets folder too?

EDIT: Turns out my issue with adding images dynamically is better solved by serving files directly from a Node.js server.

Comment: why arent you using `ng serve`? thats what its there for

Comment: It's intended to rebuild while in production.

Comment: are you saying that about `ng serve` or `ng build --watch`?

Comment: It's running on a node server, I need it to work with `ng build`

Comment: and it will, use `ng serve` whild testing then use `ng build` to build the app for use with a node server

Comment: You should have your files served directly via your nodejs webserver if you need to add images dynamically in production.

Comment: @David I suspected I was doing it wrong, any idea/guide on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put your images in a directory outside of angular's dist folder
2. Have nodejs webserver serve statically files from that directory (or have your proxy, e.g. nginx, do it directly if nodejs is behind a proxy)
3. Instead of referencing "assets/.../file" in your templates/component, reference the url of the image file served directly by the webserver/proxy